# What are love and marriage according to Hinduism?

Tags: scripture, belief, marriage, love

What is love according to Hinduism? What is marriage according to Hinduism?

What do scriptures say about them?

Comment: Love is God. Just as God cannot be defined, Love too cannot be defined. God is an experience, all attempts at defining or understanding God are incomplete, similarly Love can only be experienced, it cannot really be fully understood. It is Love that runs the Universe. :) However by love I do not mean the 'attachment' between man and woman that commonly occurs in human relationships. but this love is more spontaneous, unconditional and happens as a result of total self-knowledge. All the best.

Comment: @Sai then why divorces happen?

Comment: Good question. According to me, marriage does not mean love, as I have described in the comment above! I said that the so called 'love' between man and women is simply attachment. It is not REAL LOVE. That is the reason that sometimes divorces could ther, because of expectations and desires that come due to attachment. However in most of the cases, the attachment slowly becomes love. This love has to expand from family to city, from city to state, from state to country, from country to whole world, and finally all of creation. Such Love is Divine Love and is the goal of sadhakas. All the best.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi The marriage according to vedic standards is to limit your own sex life, because sex is putting to much focus on material pleasures. So with marriage you restrict ones sex so the focus will be on spiritual pleasure, and picking up concesness obout God. The non egoistic love has nothing to do with marriage, true love will never discriminate, yoga is love because it represents to unite, to connect with the whole existance.

Comment: Do read the Narada Bhakti Sutras which talk about different types of love. Mentioning it all here would be too long.

Comment: There is nothing like love marriage in Aryan Culture. Hinduism was name given to us after the Dwapar Yug. So in Aryan Culture there were Swamvars. You can think of them as love marriage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will answer on the love part. The [*Narada Bhakti Sutras*](http://www.artoflivinguniverse.org/2012/11/narada-bhakti-sutras-sri-sri-ravi.html) or the aphorisms of love talk at great length about *Bhakti* or divine love. I am sharing a couple of *Shlokas* here with the meaning:

Shloka 5:

> || Yat Prapya Na Kinchid Vanchati, Na Shochati, Na Dweshti, Na Ramate,
>   Notsahi Bhavati ||

Meaning:

> "Having attained that, there is no more craving, no desires, there is
>   no sadness, you do not hate anything, nothing else seems more
>   rejoicing. (you are not over excited about anything)."

Shloka 6:

> ||Yat Gyatva Matto Bhavati, Stabdho Bhavati, Atmaramo Bhavati||

Meaning:

> "Knowing which you become intoxicated, so still deep within
>   you; you are reposing in the SELF."

Comment: Also, this doesn't address the marriage part, so you should add something on that.  Sorry for giving you so many instructions!

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: lol your instructions are more than welcome :)
I will add the numbers although I do not know any scripture that talks about marriage.