# Definition of love in Hinduism

Tags: belief, love

What is described about love in Hinduism? Love between a man and a woman?

Comment: For question about love according to Hinduism, it's already asked  [What are love and marriage according to Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10200/5212).

Comment: Adultery and fornication is a strict no no in all religions including hinduism. So if you're thinking of dating or copulating with someone else's wife then that's adultery and a huge sin ... OR if you're thinking of having intercourse without marrying your partner then that's fornication, which is impure in the eyes of God. Love between a man and woman should be pure. It should be between two married couple (husband and wife).

Comment: Though I cannot understand the meaning of the word "pure" but still thanks a lot @TheCrimsonUniverse

Comment: By pure you should understand 'that' which is accepted by God ... And marriage (which is a holy act) is the means through which that pure love is practiced.

Comment: @GopalBiswas certain words don't have definition and we still use it. But they can be experienced. Pure love example: Radha Krishna

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are love and marriage according to Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10200/what-are-love-and-marriage-according-to-hinduism)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about lust. Love is universal, it can never be between distinct entities. When one realises oneness, true love follows. The sense of man and woman is dead when one attains true love.

However, we see that in nature every object animate or inanimate tries to attain oneness knowingly or unknowingly. For, instance we dress according to mainstream since we want to feel one. Carnality is a futile attempt to unite the masculine and the feminine principles and so on. Such attempts are worthless as its foundation is itself based on change. Like, the mainstream apparel fashion changes etc. and everytime we too change.

This can never result in love, it leads to despair as is widely evident. So love has no boundaries, it is simply infinitely vast, strong and invincible.