# Romantic love in Hinduism?

Tags: love

Are there any scriptures that discuss romantic love? If yes what do these scriptures have to say about romantic love? Do any of these scriptures, infer that romatic love is a form of true love or not?

Are there any reference to romantic love in the Bhagavad Gita?

Comment: What do you mean by romantic love?

Comment: @Vikas The love between a pair of lovers.

Comment: without love Karna in Mahabharata wouldn't have kids. They must have respected each other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Definition of love in Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/28958/5212) and [What are love and marriage according to Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10200/5212)

Comment: Radhe Krishna love you are looking for I guess. What else can be better example than them. Apart from them, there are Dushyanta - Shakuntala, Arjuna - Subhadra, Aniruddha -  Usha and lot more can be found. They all fell in love with each other and later did marriage. But there were also lots of troubles that they all faced while they were in love with each other. But at last they got happy ending.

Comment: why **romantic love** mentioned so many times in the question?

Comment: It is called Gandharva vivaha - happened between Dushyanta & Shakuntala. But that type of love marriage is reserved mainly for Kshatriyas. not today's modern bike-riding romeos.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any scriptures that discuss romantic love? ... Do any of these scriptures, infer that romatic love is a form of true love or not?

**The Gandharva vivaha is one form of relationship between a man and woman that is based on romantic interest.**

From the [*Manusmriti*](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199807.html):

> The mutual union of the bride and bridegroom, through love is to be known as the “Gāndharva” form; it has sexual intercourse for its end and it has its source in lust.

Also other Dharma Shastras:

> Gautama (4. 10).—‘When the girl loves a man and herself becomes united
>   to him, it is the Gāndharva form.’
>
> Baudhāyana (1. 11. 6).—‘The Gāndharva consists in the mutual union of
>   the loving bride and the loving bridegroom.’
>
> Āpāstamba-Dharmasūtra (2. 11. 20).—‘When the couple become united
>   through mutual love, it is the Gāndharva.’
>
> Vaśiṣṭha (1. 33).—‘It is the Gāndharva when the man loving the girl
>   who loves himself, and is similar to himself, marries her.’
>
> Viṣṇu (24. 23).—‘When ṭhe couple in love with one another, become
>   united, independently of the parents,—it is the Gāndharva.’
>
> Yājñavalkya (1. 61).—‘The Gāndharva is accomplished by mutual
>   agreement.’
>
> Āśvalāyana-Gṛhyasūtra (1. 6. 1. 5).—‘It is Gāndharva when the man
>   marries the girl after coming to a mutual agreement.’
>
> Devala (Vīramitrodaya-Saṃskāra, p. 855).—‘When in a sacred place, the
>   man and the woman become united by mutual agreement, through love, it
>   is the fifth form of marriage, the Gāndharva.’
>
> Hārīta (Do., p. 856).—‘When the girl herself selects the bridegroom,
>   it is Gāndharva.’

Then your next question:

> If yes what do these scriptures have to say about romantic love?

This form of marriage [is bad](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199816.html):

> From the other remaining inferior marriages are born sons, addicted to
>   saying harsh and untrue words, and despisers of the Vedic Dharma.

Comment: Take a relook at your last statement - **From the other remaining inferior marriages are born sons, addicted to saying harsh and untrue words, and despisers of the Vedic Dharma**.  Bharata,  the son of Shakuntala and Dushyanta was there, contrary to the statement @Ikshvaku

Comment: @srimannarayanakv There are other factors like education and upbringing that can affect how a person ends up being. So Bharata may have been born with an inferior nature but ended up with a good nature due to education and self-control.